# Scroll position of a div id in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using ReactJS and GatsbyJS (v2) I have a `header` component that sits `fixed` over `div id="outerContainer"` in the parent `layout` component.

To toggle class on scroll position below `100px`, I would generally use `window.scrollY < 100`.

However, due to the body class with the style `overflow:hidden` and `outerContainer` with `overflow: scroll`, the `window` scroll position does not change.

How can I define `outerContainer.scrollY < 100` from a child component, whilst referencing the `outerContainer` of the parent for scroll position?

**Layout.js**

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <div id="outerContainer" ref={el => (this.outerContainer = el)}>
      <div className="content">{children}</div>
    </div>
    <Header />
  </div>
);
```

**Header.js**

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      navScrolled: true
    };
    this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      const navScrolled = outerContainer.scrollY < 100;
      if (navScrolled !== this.state.navScrolled) {
        this.onScroll(navScrolled);
      }
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {...}
  ...
}
```

My first thought is that I should perform function in `layout.js` and use `props` pass the state down. Is this the best option or perhaps is there another way that would keen everything in `header.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first thought is correct, parent class is proper place for your `onScroll` callback, because the scroll position is a property of your entire layout, not of header which only uses it.

Also, by keeping `onScroll` in parent class, you keep yourself able to pass it to outerContainer as well, if it grows into separate class during the development, which is likely to happen.